# Changing the Font of PasswordStrength in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, css, fonts, passwords

I'm having trouble changing the font of the PasswordStrength control. I even tried creating a CSS class for it, like so:

```
.PassWordFont {
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:Verdana;
}
```

and then putting it in the markup like this

```
<asp:PasswordStrength ID="PasswordStrength1" runat="server"
  TargetControlID="txtPassword1" DisplayPosition="RightSide"
  StrengthIndicatorType="Text"
  PreferredPasswordLength="15" 
  PrefixText="Strength:"
  HelpStatusLabelID="lblLenIndicator"
  TextStrengthDescriptions="Very Poor;Weak;Average;Strong;Excellent"   
  TextCssClass="PassWordFont" 
  StrengthStyles="PWSSVeryPoor; PWSSWeak; PWSSAverage; PWSSStrong; PWSSExcellent"
  MinimumNumericCharacters="1"
  MinimumSymbolCharacters="0"
  RequiresUpperAndLowerCaseCharacters="false">
</asp:PasswordStrength>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of TextCssClass, I have previously just used CssClass.

Comment: where did you place this CssClass? Inside the password strength control??

Comment: Sorry, yes I used it instead of the TextCssClass.

Answer (score 0):

From FireBug check the css class that you have applied is loaded and having your mentioned font-size.
Verify the CSS class for that input is correct.
Also It might be the case your CSS is overridden from some where else.

Make sure your CSS is added last or after all default CSS are loaded.

Also try **font-size:12px !important;**

Comment: I tried it, I also checked my CSS and make sure that it's the last one loaded but still nothing happened. Is there any way to change the style of this control??

Comment: Can you check what is class name for your control ? or paste here your HTML i.e. Generated for your input. 
Also paste the CSS that are loaded for that input. I can suggest better than.